# Not able to exit from interactive mode of docker start

Tags: linux, docker, containers, docker-cli

I started a container using the below command connecting to linux server using putty.

`docker start -i <containerid>`

but I am not able exit from it and get back to command line, without closing the putty.

Comment: You can't exit by pressing `ctrl+C` or `ctrl+D` to linux cli?

Comment: Container has dotnet application and pressing ctrl+c shut downs the application.
Ctrl+D also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

you can do from your terminal:

- `exit`
- `ctrl+C`
- `ctrl+D`

Comment: Container has dotnet application and pressing ctrl+c shut downs the application.
Ctrl+D also doesn't work.
able to type exit but pressing enter has no reaction.

Answer (score 1):

- Start the container `docker start <container-id>`
- Set the containers to run in daemon mode `docker exec -it -d <container-id> bash` or `docker exec -d <container-id> bash`
- Enter the running container `docker exec -it <container-id> bash`
- Exit the interactive mode by typing `exit`
- Type `docker ps -a`, the container will still be running, to stop it use `docker stop <container-id>`

Example to quit interactive mode and keep the container alive:

[image: Sample]